# Know if a round is right for tablemaking?

Tags: tabletop, table-making, live-edge

Due to city code, I cut down this massive tree, which was used for a tire swing. I happen to need a coffee table so I want to select a round to turn into a resinated coffee table. But I am worried I will pick the wrong piece! A lot of pieces have mold, some pieces have holes from bugs, and some pieces may have some locked-in moisture.

Can you give me a guide to selecting the perfect round? I want to get the biggest one possible. Also, I hope to know how thin to cut it. I want to use it as a tabletop.

As far as I know, there are only 3 things to consider:

1. Is it properly dried (are there moisture pockets)?
2. Any rot or soft spots? Any undesirable splits?
3. Are there bugs, and if so can you kill them?

In terms of plaining, I was thinking to make the table about 4 inches thick, but I don't have a milling machine. Maybe I could just use a chainsaw.

About the wood: the tree was cut down two years ago and the rounds were cut out last year; so, the rounds dried in the elements for a year. They did sit in the snow, but due to the way they were positioned, the selected rounds had no notable rot. Over the past 3 months, two specific pieces were covered with a tarp and left in the garage. So, my thought was to thin-slice several pieces and then do additional drying (like with a desiccant in a sealed container) and see which slice looked best after.

[image: pictures of the rounds]

Comment: What’s the timeframe for this project? Reason I ask is that drying (like, really drying down to say 11% emc) a 4” round will take a loooong time. There could be workable strategies if you’re in a hurry, but those represent more work.

Comment: You're unlike to be able to use selected pieces of this wood the way you want. Rounds/cookies are notorious for cracking, so it's very unlikely the one you pick will survive seasoning... plus that might take a year or more! Do a search and you'll find most of the information you need.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate The wood has dried for a year. I didn't mention that I guess. I can edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

> Can you give me a guide to selecting the perfect round?

The simple answer is no.

This is separate to what you consider to be perfect not being specified in the Question. If we just make certain assumptions that amount to: hoping to select a round that's as flawless as possible *there's no way of knowing in advance which pieces will end up that way*.

The current condition of any given slice from the trunk of a tree is **zero** predictor of how they'll end up after drying is complete<sup>1</sup>. And even after something is considered well seasoned cracks can still sometimes show up later.

As you'll see if you look around online, just the initial drying of rounds or 'cookies' is fraught with difficulties and getting consistently good results is at least as much about luck as about careful planning and execution. Yields of usable rounds can be as low as 10%, even in the hands of someone with lots of experience.

So in short, you can do everything right and the round you selected to use will still crack.

---

<sup>1</sup> And this is irrespective of the species, the current moisture content of the wood, how long they've been sitting there on the ground drying the wrong way (hence the many existing drying cracks), the future drying conditions, the health of the tree when alive and various other unknowns.

Comment: Thanks, Graphus. I don't know if I mentioned this, but the wood has dried for a year in the elements. After drying for so long, I just want to do the best I can with what I've got. I was told I could just use primer and clearcoat rather than epoxy--is that true? I thought I had to use epoxy or the result would be brittle.

Comment: Please don't ask totally different questions in the comments. Ask a whole new question.

Comment: *"but the wood has dried for a year in the elements. After drying for so long"* I know it might seem like a long time, but in the big picture of wood drying a year is actually not that long. An often-repeated rule of thumb for air drying wood is "a year per inch of thickness". Now this grossly oversimplifies things but it does begin to give an idea of the kind of patience one needs — I know some woodworkers who have been drying specific pieces for more than five years, and it isn't uncommon to hear of older woodworkers who have wood they've had in storage for 10, 20, even 30+ years!

Comment: @FreeMan, is correct, the Comments is not for asking questions here. Basically if something is worth asking it's worth having its own Question (assuming you search and it isn't already covered, duplicates aren't allowed on SE). A couple of things to bear in mind if you want to ask this, first is tell us who told you.... and the following might help inform whether you'd want to pay attention to them: primer is technically *only* used to describe an opaque product used before painting. There's no 'primer' for clear finishes. There are things that are sold as "sealers" or used "to seal" [contd]

Comment: ...but that's really a different thing. And also it's a bit of a can of worms for various reasons I can't fully enumerate. But for example, some finishers and woodworkers don't use, and have never used, a "sealer": the basic truth is that the first coat of any finish acts to 'seal' the wood's surface, so a separate product for this could be thought of as meaningless. (This is incidentally also why at least two coats are needed for virtually every finish to look OK.)

Answer (score 1):

Find a local commercial saw mill that has a kiln and see what they'd charge you to kiln dry a few of your cookies. I wouldn't think they'd charge significantly more for more than one cookie, but I might be wrong.

This will speed up the drying process, especially since you want a 4" thick table, and it's the best way to kill any critters living in it.

Drying several gives you options when they're done, based on what happened to them during drying. Use any defects (cracks, soft spots, etc.) as design features in the final table.

If they all turn out to be usable to some extent, sell the others (as is or as finished tables) to offset the cost of drying.